# Concatenate elements of two string arrays jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays of strings called old_array and new_array, and I want to concatenate them together like thus:

```
old_array = "fd.com/product1/,fd.com/product2/,fd.com/product3/"

new_array = "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg"

(code happens in this area)

final_array = "http://www.fd.com/product1/image1.jpg,http://www.fd.com/product2/image2.jpg,http://www.fd.com/product3/image3.jpg"
```

All I've seen are things which would tack on the second array to the first (i.e. "fd.com/product1/,fd.com/product2/,d.com/product3/,image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg") which isn't too helpful...?

Can this sort of thing be done in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var oldArray = 'fd.com/product1/,fd.com/product2/,fd.com/product3/'.split(','),
    newArray = 'image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg'.split(',');

var finalArray = oldArray.map(function(e, i) {
        return 'http://' + e + newArray[i];
    });

document.write(finalArray);
```

Comment: You're right it works, I'm confused though as the docs state it's the other way around: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's not jQuery, just vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this without using jQuery...

```
final_array= [];
for (var i=0,j=old_array.length; i<j; i++) {
    final_array.push('http://' + old_array[i] + new_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript concat() as follows -

```
var old_array = ["fd.com/product1/","fd.com/product2/","fd.com/product3/"];
var new_array = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];
var final_array = old_array.concat(new_array);
alert (final_array);
```

Comment: This is exactly the result that the OP states he *doesn't* want.